# Trying to find a command so I can get string (e.g. name) out of a bigger string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, filter

I've been trying to find a command so I can get the name out of a string formatted like `"some string some string <name> some string"`

I managed to make a code for this kind of job but if there is a better way, let's say a command for exactly that, I'd be very glad.

Code example:

```
def findName(str):
    indexOne = str.index('<')
    indexTwo = str.index('>')
    resultList = []

    for i in str:
        if str.index(i) > indexOne and str.index(i) < indexTwo:
            resultList.append(i)



    return "".join(resultList)
```

Comment: please include some code

Comment: What _is_ the code you managed to make, and what's the problem with it?

Comment: Okay i've included my code

Comment: Do you want a Linux command instead of your custom program?

Comment: Sure! I mean the the program is for a windows laptop but still some knowlegde wont hurt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your solution with [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings):

```py
>>> string = "some string some string <name> some string"
>>> string[string.index("<")+1:string.index(">")]
'name'
```

Or you can use a regex and [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search) for this:

```py
import re

string = "some string some string <name> some string"
match = re.search("<(.*)>", string)
if match:
    print("Found:", match.group(1))
else:
    print("Not found")
```

Output

```
Found: name
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine . Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string that is like

```py
a = 'somestring1 somestring2 somestring3 <Stack Overflow> somestring4'
```

Then you can do something like this:

```py
import re
words = re.findall(r'<(.*)>',a)
print(words)
```

Comment: Not really what ive been looking for but thanks anyways. The point is that the program finds the name (which is stored bettween <>) in any string

Comment: At that point you might as well just use `a[36:-12]`, this is so specific to the input that using a regular expression is pointless.

Comment: @XlorokoptikoGiaGkazon I see. Well, I posted this answer before you edited the question. From the previous version of your question, I couldn't understand exactly whether the `<>` bounds were part of the name or not. And I had a hunch that you were looking for something like RegEx, and so i posted it so that you can flexibly edit it in your code as per your requirement. Thanks for pointing out, btw.

Comment: @jonrsharpe My answer was actually sent before the OP has edited the question, wheren it wasn't as clear that the `<>` bounds are part of the name as it is in the newer version of the question. Nevertheless, I have edited my answer. Thanks for pointing out, btw.